# Duda en listas de python

Tags: python

el problema ya esta resuelto pero me quedo una gran duda que expongo.

Por que en la primera lista [13,6] termina hasta ahí y no termina hasta -1 como la otra?

```
cociente = int(0)
dividendo = int(input("Favor ingresa dividendo: "))
divisor = int(input("Favor ingresa divisor: "))
dividendo = dividendo - divisor
dividendos = []
while(dividendo >= 0):
    dividendos.append(dividendo) #esta lista esta agarrando los dividendos de la cuarta linea
    cociente = cociente + 1
    dividendo = dividendo - divisor
    dividendos.append(dividendo) #esta esta agarrando los dividendos de la linea de arriba
    print(dividendos)
print("El cociente es: ", cociente)
print("El residuo es:", dividendos[-1] )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el print() antes del append y ya vera el porque error de logica!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es fácil, el print de la lista lo haces al finalizar cada iteración del while. En tu primera iteración tu lista solo contiene 2 elementos [13,6] para la segunda vuelta conserva el 13,6 pero le agrega el 6 y -1, y ya con el -1 termina el while siendo que dio dos iteraciones.